# Binary Search Tree: If two different traversals are given, will there be a unique tree that satisfies the traversals?

Tags: binary-trees, binary-search-trees

I have come across algorithms that can create a BST if any two of the 3 traversals are given (there would be three different algorithms for the 3 combinations)

[This is an example](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/)

I was wondering, is it guaranteed that a tree generated would be unique? Or rather, can multiple trees be generated satisfying the two traversals?

I am pretty certain that there will only be one tree that satisfies two traversals, because that is how everyone treats the problem, and it seems somewhat logical, but I *have never seen it written explicitly* anywhere.

Any sources that answer theoretical questions like this about Binary Search Trees would be helpful as well.

Comment: If the tree that you want to construct is know to be a BST, then we actually know the inorder traversal, by ordering the nodes from small to large. So, for a BST it suffices to know only the pre-order or post-order in order to reconstruct it.

Comment: There are examples of two different BSTs with the same pre- and postorder traversals. As Hendrick said, though, knowing the inorder traversal and one of the others determines the tree uniquely.